How to connect a PS4 to a local network using PPPoE from a Docker container on a Raspberry Pi
I have a Raspberry Pi with eth0 connected to the internet and the local network. On eth1 I have a PS4 connected with a PPPoE connection, I want it to connect to the eth0 local network using PPPoE from a Docker container with Alpine.
I can't get it to run in Docker

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
